# How to split a Multiindex row into two Multiindex rows?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe with multiple levels of Multiindex. One of the levels is `latlon`, which is a string of the numbers with an `;` between them.
However, for further processing, it makes much more sense to have a `lat` level and a `lon` level. with floats for the numbers, instead of the combined string.

How do I best partition this level into two levels?

I have a solution, but it doesn't seem very *pythonic* and requires building a new dataframe, so I'm looking for a better way.

**MWE:**

Set up a simple test df:

```
number = [1, 2, 3]
name = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
latlon = ['10.1;50.1', '12.2;52.2', '13.3;53.3']
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([number, name, latlon], 
                                 names=('number','name', 'latlon'))
data = np.random.rand(4,3)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=idx)
```

(Original data has 10 levels in the Multiindex and is of size `25000, 750`)
As you can see, `latlon` is easily human-readble, but not particularly useful. I want a `lat` and `lon` level, with floats.

What I've come up with:

```
# get a list of them, to iterate through
latlons = df.columns.get_level_values('latlon').to_list()
# set up emptly lists and start iterating
lats = []
lons = []
for i in latlons:
# do some string searches and split by positions
    start_str = i.find(';')+1 
    end_str = i.find('\n')
    lon_str = i[0:start_str-1]
    lon = float(lon_str)
    lons.append(lon)
    lat_str = i[start_str:end_str]
    lat = float(lat_str)
    lats.append(lat)
```

Now there's two lists, one with lats and one with lons, which can be used to build a new index and thus a new df:

```
number = df.columns.get_level_values('number').to_list()
# I can't reuse 'number' from the initial setup, since the original
# comes from an excel import, so I must extract it here.
name = df.columns.get_level_values('name').to_list()
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([number, name, lats, lons], 
                                 names=('number','name', 'lat', 'lon'))
data = df.values
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=idx)
```

This works and is very easy to understand, but it all feels very hacky and one hickup away from mixing up data.

Is there a simpler/better way?

Answer (score 2):

I would temporarily convert the MultiIndex to DataFrame to benefit from `DataFrame`'s methods:

```
new_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
 df.columns.to_frame()
   .pipe(lambda d: d.join(d.pop('latlon')
                           .str.split(';', expand=True)
                           .set_axis(['lat', 'lon'], axis=1)
                         ))
   .astype({'lat': float, 'lon': float})
)

df.columns = new_idx
```

Output:

```
number         1         2         3
name         foo       bar       baz
lat         10.1      12.2      13.3
lon         50.1      52.2      53.3
0       0.796467  0.769194  0.733470
1       0.272247  0.558985  0.345007
2       0.209480  0.669443  0.648002
3       0.466146  0.262006  0.236987
```

Comment: that's quite clever, but also seems hacky to me? Also, now `lat` and `lon` still are strings, instead of float. Interestingly, `%%timeit` gives 1.81 ms for your solution, whereas my loop only takes 819µs. Wasn't expecting that.

Comment: @JC_CL why hacky? Indexes unfortunately have much less methods than DataFrames, it's quite easier to temporarily convert. Regarding the types, you can add a conversion step (see edit). Regarding the timings, you have to be careful, what is the exact code and dataset? How does it scale up (for thousands of columns?) In any case you seemed to be looking for a more concise/pythonic solution, not necessarily more performant, no? ;)

Comment: You're right about the performance, I didn't state that, just because I was simply expecting my solution to be slow (as my solutions always are... I'll see how it behaves with the large data. For the test data, your float added a full ms to it). "hacky", of course is hard to objectively define, but turning an index into a dataframe and back is probably just as "bad" as killing it and rebuilding it.

Comment: I've now tested it with a `(22859, 261)` shape dataframe and your solutions times to 6.04 ms, whereas my original one clocks in at a bit more than half that (3.45 ms).

Answer (score 1):

extract the index, split, and rebuild the index:

```py
arr = df.columns
arrays = [arr.get_level_values(num) for num in range(arr.nlevels)]
*arrays, latlon = arrays
latlon = latlon.str.split(';')
lon = latlon.str[-1].astype(float).rename('lon')
lat = latlon.str[0].astype(float).rename('lat')
arrays.extend([lat,lon])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays)
df
number         1         2         3
name         foo       bar       baz
lat         10.1      12.2      13.3
lon         50.1      52.2      53.3
0       0.469529  0.356716  0.287799
1       0.786352  0.557752  0.318536
2       0.877670  0.503199  0.225858
3       0.324959  0.253091  0.967328
```

Comment: That works, but oddly enough, it's also slower than my solution (1.02ms, though I had to introduce a `df2` to make `%%timeit` work.

Comment: Also slower (6.04 ms) than my solution (3.45 ms) for a `(22859, 261)` dataframe.

Comment: Oh that's great; if your code is faster it'd be better if you use that instead. plus your code is still readable